# Automatically creating bins for a numeric variable in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, tidyverse, binning

So I have a variable as below.

```
var <- c(0L, 5L, 4L, 115L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 365L, 4L, 20L, 61L, 365L, 
0L, 365L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 72L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 105L, 150L, 0L, 365L, 
0L, 1L, 28L, 161L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 12L, 0L, 10L, 49L, 7L, 2L, 51L, 
0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 17L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 44L, 
0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 87L, 0L, 321L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 140L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 20L, 0L, 
4L, 14L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 39L, 4L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 7L)
```

I want to create bins of different sizes (or same no matter) to categorize and plot as a bar chart for this variable.

I know it's possible to find automatic/reccommended binning however I am unsure how to do so in R?

Tried using the `bin()` function to no avail . I read about the Jenks method as well, but is there a way to create the best possible bins in R?

Would like to use it to plot a bar plot in ggplot.

Comment: `cut(var, breaks = 3)` to get data divided in 3 bins. Is this what you want?

Comment: It shouldn't be like just 3 cuts tho; It should be the best cuts for the distribution based on the spread of the variable.

Comment: Are you planning to you the cuts anywhere else or just plot them?

Comment: just need them to create different bars for a bar plot

Comment: something like Bar 1: 0-2, bar 2 : 2-10 , bar 3: 10-200; etc. Basically I need to know where the best spots to cut would be. Different methods exists I think? Jenks is what I have heard of.

Comment: The `histogram` function takes different methods. Although the breaks are done evenly. eg `hist(var, breaks = "FD", plot = FALSE)`. Although since it seems you want to plot, just do `hist(var, 40)` this will produce a histogram with 40 breaks

Comment: Or `?quantile` based breaks maybe? `qv <- round(quantile(var)); cut(var, qv[!duplicated(qv)], include.lowest=TRUE)` ?

Comment: hmmm i bet either could work

Comment: or just pass the breaks you want as a vector to `cut` and pass the resulting object to `plot`: var_cut <- cut(var$value, breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400))
plot(var_cut)

Comment: @thelatemail that's an idea i didn't think of; answer and I can approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description sounds like you're wanting to plot a histogram of `var`.  This can be done easily enough in `ggplot` using `geom_histogram`.  The key here is that `ggplot` likes to have a data frame, so you just have to specify your variable in a dataframe first, which you can do inside the `ggplot()` function:

```
ggplot(data.frame(var), aes(var)) + geom_histogram(color='black', alpha=0.2)
```

Gives you this:

[image]

The default is to use 30 bins, but you can specify either number of bins via `bins=` or the size of the bins via `binwidth=`:

```
ggplot(data.frame(var), aes(var)) + geom_histogram(bins=10, color='black', alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

If you want to plot the basic bar geom, then `geom_histogram()` works just fine.  If you change to use the `stat_bin()` function instead, it will perform the same binning method, but then you can apply and use a different geom if you want to:

```
ggplot(data.frame(var), aes(var)) +
  stat_bin(geom='area', bins=10, alpha=0.2, color='black')
```

[image]

If you're looking to grab just the numbers/data from "binning" a variable like you have, one of the simplest ways might be to use `cut()` from `dplyr`.

Use of `cut()` is pretty simple.  You specify the vector and a `breaks=` argument.  Breaks can be specified a list of places where you want to "cut" your data (or "bin" your data), or you can just set `breaks=10` and it will give you an evenly cut set of 10 bins.  The result is a `factor` with `levels=` that correspond to the range for each of the breaks.  In the case of `var` with `breaks=10`, you get the following:

```
> var_cut <- cut(var, breaks = 10)
> levels(var_cut)
 [1] "(-0.365,36.5]" "(36.5,73]"     "(73,110]"      "(110,146]"     "(146,182]"     "(182,219]"     "(219,256]"    
 [8] "(256,292]"     "(292,328]"     "(328,365]"
```